# Using braces for assigning constants in constructor initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering the following `c++11` toy example:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int aA) : a_{aA} {};

protected:
    Foo();

private:
    const int a_;
};
```

According to [this guideline](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-list), braces should be preferable for initializing objects. **Scott Meyers**, however, says that you should choose between parenthesis or braces and use it consistently.

Keeping in mind the first link, which is the **Bjarne Stroustrup** recommendation, is there any side effects of assigning constants in the constructor's initializer list with braces? I am asking it, because **none of them has specifically given an example for assigning constants in the constructor**.

Comment: It's "braces",  not "bracers" - edited accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, @NeilButterworth. Thanks for fixing the typo!

Comment: Sometimes they are not equivalent. `vector<int>(100, 42)` is not the same as `vector<int>{100, 42}`.

Comment: Also, `s/assigning/initializing/`

Comment: You cannot use one form exclusively, so whichever form you chose there will be exceptions.

Comment: @BoPersson It seems to me that it is the point, though. It makes less-straightforward constructors stand out.

Comment: What “constants” are you talking about?

Comment: Constant data members of a class